# How to estimate number of Laue Spot

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Why are "Laue Spots" spots instead of rings? Or is there an effective way to estimate the number of Laue spots?  I can't find any formulas or theory concerning this issue. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Laue spots / rings are just the transmission mode analogue of Bragg diffraction spots / rings. A crystalline sample will show a spot pattern while a powdered sample (lots of small randomly oriented crystallites) will show rings.

See any entry level solid-state textbook (e.g. First chapters of Kittell) for a derivation of the "Laue condition" that determines where these spots appear.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need some efficient way to estimate the magnitude of order of the number of spots, is there some effective way to estimate?

Comment: It will depend on how finely the powder is ground. Assuming random orientation of the crystals, each crystal illuminated by the X-rays will generate a pattern of spots. If the crystals are large there will be few of them and you'll get a pattern of discrete spots. If the crystals are small there will be so many of them that the spots merge to create the rings.